# Prevent data from touching axes

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

In MATLAB, is it possible to quickly/concisely increase the default padding around data in plots? In other words, I don't want the data to be too close to the axes.

[image]

Comment: In addition to the answer by @jodag, you could similarly use `xlim` and `ylim` to address this. It is possible to automate the use of these as well.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan The problem with that is having to manually set the limits based on the range of the data. Too much effort!

Comment: that's good feedback, though I use these in an automated way (not manually).  Wanted to leave in comments for future SO users.  I personally prefer automating my figures with `xlim` and `ylim` but I understand different strokes for different folks, and all that.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Oh in that case perhaps you could share the method as an answer; it's not clear to me how to do that

Comment: done and done.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If simply padding the existing axis is sufficient then the following should work. Say you want to add 10% to each side.

```
plot(...);
scale = 1.1;
ax = axis();
xc = 0.5 * (ax(1)+ax(2));
yc = 0.5 * (ax(3)+ax(4));
c = [xc,xc,yc,yc];
axis(scale * (ax - c) + c);
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach is similar to @[jodag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790047/jodag)'s excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53094328/8239061) and is entirely my *preference*. Posting this based on OP's request in the comments. I have no doubt there may be more efficient ways of doing this.

**Key Idea:** Automate use of `xlim` and `ylim`.

Minimal working example:

```
d = 0.10;     % 10 percent
c = [1-d 1+d];
X = 5 + 5*rand(10,2);

plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'rs')

Xrng = xlim;
Yrng = ylim;
xlim(c.*Xrng);  % Adjust X Range
ylim(c.*Yrng);  % Adjust Y Range
```

Other ways to automate this using these properties:

1. Use a handle for the plot `h = plot()` and modify properties
2. Use the `set`, `get`, and `gca` commands.

No doubt there are other approaches still.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, you are right, I made a mistake.  The idea is clear and I'll fix when I get the chance.  Thank you for pointing that out.